# How can I beat the rock spiders on level 4 of Battle Quest?

Tags: nintendo-land

On the Legend of Zelda Battle Quest attraction in Nitendo Land I'm having some trouble getting past the big rock spiders like in level four. They dodge my charge shots, and they only seem to take damage from the head, so taking them out before they reach you is very tricky. Is there any better way to take them out aside from spamming arrows and hoping you hit their head? I've noticed a lot of the Miiverse messages on the level note having trouble with the spiders, but not how to beat them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Archer you can use a charged arrow shot to topple over the spider simply by hitting it's hard shell/back. It will fall over (only with a charged shot) and expose it's belly, which is fair game to shoot. You can shoot charged shots or spam uncharged shots, and refill your arrows. This is also useful in the "boss" fight at the end of the level, as you can topple the spider to give yourself a few extra seconds to take out the weaker targets before killing the spider.

Unfortunately I don't know any strategies for the sword wielding option as I don't have a wii motion plus controller.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways to beat it is to play with a partner. Then if the spider gets you your partner can hit him and he will let go of you. The spiders back is literally unable to be hit.
Shoot them in the head and you do not even have to use a power shot. I'm on level 3 of the 5 secret levels, and the spiders come up a lot.